# How to resolve Eclipse 'Type Class "X" could not be found'

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am getting this annoying JPA validation error in Eclipse but cannot find where it defined anywhere, when the class is opened no error shows. But they do appear in the package explorer/problems tab.

Heres an example of where CurrencyType.class is defined...

```
/**
 * UserSubscription
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_subscriptions", schema = "public")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "userSubsWithCount",
    entities = {@EntityResult(entityClass = UserSubscription.class)},
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "TOTALCOUNT")}
)
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name="currency_enum",typeClass=CurrencyType.class),
    @TypeDef(name="sub_option_enum",typeClass=SubscriptionOptionType.class),
    @TypeDef(name="sub_state_enum",typeClass=SubscriptionStateType.class)
})
public class UserSubscription implements java.io.Serializable {
```

And the class itself (in a different package but same .jar)

```
public class CurrencyType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType<Currency> {
     
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws SQLException{
        try{
            Currency type = Currency.valueOf(rs.getString(names[0]).toUpperCase());
            if(type == null){
                System.err.println("CurrencyConvertor: Null returned from CurrencyConvertor.valueOf, pgObject.getValue() = " + rs.toString());
            }else{
                return type;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.err.println("CurrencyConvertor: Returning null!: "+rs.getString(names[0]));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value,
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(
            index,
            value != null ?
                ((Currency) value).name().toLowerCase() :
                null,
            Types.OTHER
        );
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Show us where the class is, too.

Comment: Perhaps "in a different package" is why they're not found?

Comment: My advice, just turn these JPA validations off, as far as I can remember they never really worked properly always showing these kind of unknown annoying errors. It is usually some weird behavior based on which plugins you have installed in your Eclipse. Google "eclipse jpa validator bug" and you will see. You are better off without it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes this is what I am trying to do but I cannot find the Validation setting for this error, there is no definition for 'Type Class Could Not Be Found' so I cannot turn it off

Comment: I was referring to the entire thing, Window -> Preferences -> Validation search for JPA Validator and disable it both manual/build... if you are on a mac... the Preferences menu is not under it